# Windows 10, before browsing, hard drive size 120 GB, after browsing facebook and watching some videos, size is 125GB

Tags: windows

I have Win10, when I turn on my laptop, C drive has 120GB, after browsing some videos on facebook and youtube, it gets to 125GB. After I restart my computer it gets to 120GB, why is that?

Here is how it was before watching only videos on youtube and facebook:
[image: before]

Look how it became after without adding anything such as copying and the like:
[image: after]

and just now, without doing anything:
[image: After After]

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to used space?

Comment: It's impossible for a disk to become larger.  Can you provide a screenshot to clarify your question by editing your question?

Comment: I attached it, and you can see.

Comment: This will be the os and/or browser managing temporary files in the background.

Comment: Yes, we can see the screenshots showing nothing of what you wrote. They consistently show the the exact same size (118GB), as expected, and also as expected a variable free space (read above ^^^).

Answer (score 1):

Your hard-disk isn't magically changing size. That is impossible.

What you are observing is fluctuations in the amount of free space on the C: drive.

That is perfectly normal.

Even if you are not actively using the machine Windows (and other software installed) will be doing behind the screens housekeeping. This happens continuously and will cause the amount of free disk-space to vary.

The page-file gets resized on a regular basis. Temp-files and log-files grow and get cleaned up again. Windows Updates and other application updates get downloaded in the background (and thrown away again after installation). All that is visible as fluctuations in free disk-space.

The variation can be anywhere from a few megabytes (hardly noticeable) to several gigabytes (quite noticeable). It really depends on what software exactly is installed on the computer and your usage pattern of that software.

And on a nearly full disk the variation is more noticeable, because there is so little free space to start with.

So nothing to worry about.

PS. You might consider moving some of your stuff from C: to D:. Current Windows versions really like to have at least 15 to 20 GB free on C:. Disk-space is getting a bit thight on your C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

You are (most likely) misinterpreting the numbers. The total size (“of 118 GB”) stays the same in every screenshot, as expected. What changes is the amount of free space *of these 118 GB*. So you have the following:

| Image | Free Space | Used Space (calculated) | Total Space |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.6 GB | 118 - 12.6 = 105.4 GB | 118 GB |
| 2 | 11.8 GB | 118 - 11.8 = 106.2 GB | 118 GB |
| 3 | 11.2 GB | 118 - 11.2 = 106.8 GB | 118 GB |

Not sure how you’re coming up with 120 GB, but whatever!

Because there are lots of temporary and cached data on C:, the amount of used space can change at any time. Furthermore, Windows (or other software) could be installing updates in the background. There’s just a lot going on, even when your PC is seemingly idle.